# Is "to be at inspire" a correct way of saying "I am inspired"?

Tags: idioms

Today I received an email with the sender using " I will be at inspire". Never heard of this collocation! Is it right to say so?
Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Sounds like the name of a bar or restaurant.

Comment: Is the writer a native English speaker?

Comment: I agree with Lambie.  "I will be at inspire" seems to mean that he will be at a place called "inspire".  Maybe not a bar ... perhaps a park or a town.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not grammatically correct. The word "inspire" is a verb, not a noun. As a verb, "inspire" is an action and can not be a place or a thing, so its impossible to be "at" inspire.

It sounds like the writer made a mistake or was playing with the language by turning the concept of inspire into a state of being. However if this is the case, then using the noun "inspiration", as in "I will be at "inspiration" would be marginally more accurate.

Comment: Thank you Elizabeth! Your answer is convincing and the fact that I did not find any such thing at either Webster or Longman corroborates your standpoint.